# How to create virtual email addresses with mailrule iredmail

Tags: apache, email, centos, iredmail

I have been asked to create special mailbox with theese functions:

1) Create new mailbox `test@domain.com` (SMTP, POP3).

2) **Incomming messages:** 
Arrange that this mailbox will recieve messages to virtual email addresses in `test.xxx@domain.com` form. Where xxx is any number with variable length. This is typically achieved in catch-all mailbox with regular expression mailrule (where TO or CC matches `test\.\d+@domain.com`)

3) **Outgoing messages:**
Enable login `test@domain.com` to send email with variable "FROM" field according to point 2) This is typically achieved by enabling any "FROM" for that mailbox.

**Overall purpose of this mailbox is this:**

There exists any reservation number in the system. For example 1500278.
employee sends email to client from CRM and email address `test.1500278@domain.com` and this email is registered in CRM.
Client replies to `test.1500278@domain.com` and this email is received to `test@domain.com`
system picks that mailbox using POP3 and assigns that email to reservation number 1500278.

so all need to know how to create this mail
the mail server running on Centos apache iRedMail
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it by **Memcached**
and here is the link http://memcached.org/